# mod_rewrite subdirectories as variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to rewrite "/products/MFG/date/SKU.html" to "MFG-SKU.html"

Our current rewrite below only rewrites to "SKU.html".

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/
RewriteRule /([^/]*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

How can I access MFG as a variable to include before the SKU?

An example URL would be:

http://example.com/products/MFG/2010-04-01/1234.html => http://example.com/MFG-1234.html

MFG and 1234 are variables that would change.

Comment: Please provide an URL example (real URL example) -- it's much more easier to build a rule when seeing what needs to be done. I need `from URL` => `to URL`.

Comment: Thanks, updated the post to reflect an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one should do the job for you:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/[0-9-]+/([^/]+)\.html$ $1-$2.html [R=301,L]
```

1. It will redirect `/products/MFG/2010-04-01/1234.html` to `/MFG-1234.html`.
2. It does not validate the parameters (MFG, SKU, date):

   - The `MFG` part can be anything within 1 path segment (which means any character except slash `/`): can be letters, digits, Unicode chars etc. If you need to limit it -- just modify the pattern `([^/]+)` to whatever restrictions you want to have;
   - The `date` part has very simple validation -- only digits and `-` is allowed. So even `123456-09876` will work. Once again -- if you need to have more precise validation just chnage the pattern;
   - The `SKU` part --same validation in place as for `MFG` part.
3. This rule is intended to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.